# docker file entrypoint file runs in loop

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sh

I have a dockerfile like this

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

COPY . /app

COPY entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

RUN npm i -g sequelize-cli

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "./entrypoint.sh" ]

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

## entrypoint.sh

```
sequelize-cli db:drop
sequelize-cli db:create
sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

The entrypoint.sh file keeps running in a loop after running the docker file

Comment: And what is that entrypoint.sh you copy from your host drive? It's not unusual to have a daemon running from the execution of the entry point (aka a program that doesn't terminate and wait)

Comment: It looks like the entrypoint script might be missing the "shebang" line that says which interpreter to use, and the final `exec "$@"` line that tells it to execute the `CMD`.  If you're missing these parts, and have a restart policy set, that could cause the apparent looping behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is likely due to a misunderstanding of how Docker's `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` instructions work.

In Docker, the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction allows you to configure a container that will run as an executable. The command following the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction is the command that gets executed when the Docker container starts up.

The `CMD` instruction provides defaults for an executing container. These can include an executable, or they can omit the executable, in which case you must specify an `ENTRYPOINT` instruction.

In your case, the `ENTRYPOINT` is executing the `entrypoint.sh` script, and after that, the `CMD` instruction is running the `"npm", "run", "dev"` command.

Now, if your `entrypoint.sh` script is set to continuously run (perhaps due to an infinite loop in the script), it would indeed cause the behavior you are seeing. But from the script content you shared, there seems to be no such loop.

One possible issue might be that the `sequelize-cli` commands in your `entrypoint.sh` script are causing the script to rerun. The `sequelize-cli` commands you're using (`db:drop`, `db:create`, `db:migrate`) are presumably operating on a database that is within your Docker container. If the `db:drop` command is removing the database and then `db:create` and `db:migrate` are recreating it, this could somehow be causing the `entrypoint.sh` script to restart.

As a solution, you might want to separate the database initialization from your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`. You could make the database initialization a part of the Dockerfile `RUN` command instead, so it's executed during the image build process, not every time the container starts up.

If the database needs to be initialized every time the container starts, you might want to use a wrapper script that first runs the database initialization, then starts your application. That way, the initialization won't keep triggering the `ENTRYPOINT` script.

Here's an example of how you might adjust your Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

COPY . /app

COPY entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

RUN npm i -g sequelize-cli

EXPOSE 3000

RUN ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Let me know if this helped!

Comment: This answer should make it clearer that a container only runs one command; see for example [Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) in the Dockerfile documentation.